# SharePoint 2010 "Save Site as Template" with lookup fields in Lists

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

When I try to save as a template (*`Site Settings -> Site Actions -> Save Site as Template`*) my SharePoint 2010 site, created with Visual Studio 2010, I get following error:

```
SPSolutionExporter: System.FormatException: Guid should contain 32 digits 
    with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx).
at System.Guid..ctor(String g)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSolutionExporter.GetFieldSchemaXml(SPField field, 
    SPWeb web, Boolean isFieldFromWeb, Boolean removeSealedAttribute)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSolutionExporter.ExportField(SPField field, SPWeb web)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSolutionExporter.ExportFields
    (SPFieldCollection fields, String partitionName)
```

After intensive search I have found good [article](http://andrewonsoftware.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/how-to-define-lookup-column-via-caml-in-sharepoint-2010-and-avoid-errors/) explaining what is going on wrong when SharePoint lists with lookup fields are saved in a template. Additional attribute "`Overwrite="TRUE"`" must be added in lookup fields definitions in `Elements.xml` and `Schema.xml`. After I did that I am able to save my site as a template. Very good.

However, lookups stopped working! No data from target lookup List are available now and even link to the same list (where some parent / child relations are specified) do not work anymore. Simply, such lookup columns now are always empty. "`Add new item`" dialog does not provide any data to specify in lookup column of new item. What could be wrong with attribute "`Overwrite="TRUE"`"?

Thanks in advance,
Sal

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in Derek Gusoff's [blog](http://derekgusoff.wordpress.com/2013/04/26/declaratively-provisioning-a-lookup-column/).